# EditText and Button on the same line with TextView underneath?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have an `EditText` widget next to a `Button`, also with a `TextView` underneath. The `EditText` should resize and fill the screen accordingly, while the Button's width should always be only what it needs to be (I did this by setting the width to `wrap_content`).

The layout I am trying to accomplish should **not** be relative. Below is the code I have so far (some of which was found here on StackOverflow). Removing the TextView gives the desired appearance for the EditText and Button, but when the TextView is added, the view goes pretty awry.

Any insight would help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  >
    <EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" 
              android:id="@+id/EditText01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `The layout should not be relative.` why?

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't like the XML tags. It thinks it's HTML and strips it out. Instead of the <code><pre> tags, highlight the code and click the code button to format it

Comment: Relative will most likely needlessly complicate things in the future. I am new to android programming but not to programming in general. Having to specify positions all the time ends up very painful in the end. If you can do it via relative layout I would still like to see how. Also thank you for letting me know about the code formatting here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <Button

        android:text="@+id/Button01" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </Button>

    <EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/EditText01"
        android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly Falmarri. Adding 
<code>android:padding="5dip"</code> also helped make the look more uniform when compared to the LinearLayout.

Comment: While we're at it... Now how would one add additional TextView(s) just below the first?

Comment: Do the same thing. Give the TextView an id like you did the button and edittext, and on your new TextVIew set its `layout_below="@id/TextView02` or whatever the id is.